# JavaScript match function seems to halt script

Tags: javascript, regex

Yesterday 'Hnatt' was kind enough to offer the regex portion of this script :

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("hhhhhh   yadad   example.com/check?x=asdfasdf bsss ffhhh".match(/example.com\/check\?x\=([^\s]*)/)[1]);
        alert('alert 2');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I have a new question/problem/point_of_confusion. If I change 'example.com' to **not** match, the entire script stops.  I would like to know a solution other then try/catch that permits the script to continue forward. (Although, I hacked a fix with try/catch, insertion of a try catch/breaks the larger script... I don't know why. This is why I want a solution that is not comprised of try/catch).  I would also like to try to understand why this halsting happens when the 'match' function does not find a match.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("hhhhhh   yadad   exampleTwo.com/check?x=asdfasdf bsss ffhhh".match(/example.com\/check\?x\=([^\s]*)/)[1]);
        alert('alert 2');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a boiled down version. In the broader script I am using the the needle found in the haystack and assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Console says: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null* If you just want to know whether the strings matches or not, use `expressions.text(string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to not generate a script error and not use try/catch, then you need to assign the match return value to a variable and test it to see if it found a match and if it found enough matches before using it.

```
var matches = "hhhhhh   yadad   exampleTwo.com/check?x=asdfasdf bsss ffhhh".match(/example.com\/check\?x\=([^\s]*)/);
if (matches && matches.length > 1) {
    alert(matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: You can change condition to simple if(matches[1])

Comment: You can't do if (matches[1]) when matches is null without causing an error.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fz5nm/.

Comment: Really, forgot. You're right, only chain-check may be used like yours or "matches && matches[1]".

Answer (score 7):

When there's no match, the `.match()` method returns null. When you attempt to get index `[1]` of `null`, there's an error, halting the script. You should check for this, something like:

```js
var match = "hhhhhh   yadad   exampleTwo.com/check?x=asdfasdf bsss ffhhh".match(/example.com\/check\?x\=([^\s]*)/);
if (match) {
    alert(match[1]);
}
alert('alert 2');
```

Comment: just save the result to a variable, and check if that variable is not null

Comment: FYI, this doesn't necessarily work if there's only one match.  You have to check to make sure there are at least two matches before referencing matches[1].

Comment: Sure, but for this pattern if there are any `matches` there will be a `matches[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy explains why you are getting the error. You can ensure that the index operation is valid as follows :

```
alert(("hhhhhh   yadad   exampleTwo.com/check?x=asdfasdf bsss ffhhh".match(/example.com\/check\?x\=([^\s]*)/) || [])[1]);
```

This turns the match result to an empty array if the match fails.